# parse is still alive, but how to query by 'index'

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I found that Parse is now supported by the Buddy platform, but all the forum/help files from the old Parse website are gone...

What i would like to do is query for one row in a table by row number/index.

I now do this, but it seems inefficient to me to get all data and then select the row (although it works fine):

```
var thisRow = Parse.Object.extend(GlobTable);
var query= new Parse.Query(thisRow);
query.descending('updatedAt');
query.find({
  success: function(results) {

  var object = results[RowNumberThatINeed];
  //etc using object
```

@Ran, thanks! Somehow it doesn't work, Parse will store '1' for every row: 1,1,1,1. But it saves all other data ok.

```
var Object = Parse.Object.extend(LocTable);
var obj = new Object();

    obj.set("User", LocUser);
    obj.set("Happened", d);
    obj.set("Happy", b);
    obj.set("Learned",a);
    obj.set("ConnectedTo",c);
    obj.increment("rowIndex");
    obj.save({
success: function(obj) {

 updateDatabase();
 alert("Your data is saved");

},
error: function(obj, err) {
alert("Your data was not saved. Sorry..." + err);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you solution will work but you will experience a lot performance issues when your table will growth.

What i suggest to you is the following solution:

1. Add another field to your GlobTable of type **integer**. This field will be incremental field and will store your row index (let's call this field **rowIndex**)
2. Each time you save a new object to this table make sure you increment this field by using the following command:

```js
object.increment("rowIndex");
```

3. Now your query should look like the following:

```js
var thisRow = Parse.Object.extend(GlobTable);
var query= new Parse.Query(thisRow);
query.equalTo("rowIndex",RowNumberThatINeed);
query.first().then(function(result){
  // do something with the result
},function(error){
  // error handling
});
```

If you want event better performance you can create index (in MongoDb) on your rowIndex.

In my code snippets i use Promises according to the best practices.

I use **first** and not **find** because there will always be one object for this index

Comment: This is great! I'll try it as soon as i've time. I would never have thought of it.. Thanks Ran!